# When the derivatives are never zero, is the maximum of a function equal to $\infty$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x)=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f(x)=0\\
...\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_M}f(x)=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
has no solution. Can we conclude that $\max_xf(x)=\infty$? Do we need to "augment" the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ with $\infty$?

Comment: Maybe you mean supremum rather than maximum? Even a bounded function needn't have a maximum.

Comment: Consider a function that is asymptotic to a constant line (or plane).  Arctan is the classic example but.... any other would do.  $f(x) = \frac {x}{|x|+1}$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is false even if $M=1$. Take $f(x)=\arctan x$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Would instead be $\sup_{x} arctan(x)$?

Comment: In this specific example, the function has no maximum.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider the function $y=arctan(x)$.